# orderByChild().equalTo() isn't returning the id

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
 LiveData<DataSnapshot> questBadgeData = questViewModel.getBadgeSnapshotLiveData(questViewModel.getQuestId());
    Log.d("sad","score calc quest id "+questViewModel.getQuestId());
    questBadgeData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String badgeID = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.d("sad","badge id "+badgeID);
            //String icon = dataSnapshot.child("icon").getValue().toString();
            //String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            //questViewModel.setBadgeData(badgeID,icon,name);
            questViewModel.setBadgeData(badgeID,"dummy","dummy");
        }
    });
```

This is the structure of my firebase database:

[image]

```
 @NonNull
public LiveData<DataSnapshot> getBadgeSnapshotLiveData(String qid) {
    Query query = dbBadge.orderByChild("questid").equalTo(qid);
    return new FirebaseQueryLiveData(query);
}
```

This is my FirebaseQueryLiveData class

```
public class FirebaseQueryLiveData extends LiveData<DataSnapshot> {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseQueryLiveData";

private final Query query;
private final MyValueEventListener listener = new MyValueEventListener();

public FirebaseQueryLiveData(Query query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public FirebaseQueryLiveData(DatabaseReference ref) {
    this.query = ref;
}

@Override
protected void onActive() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActive");
    query.addValueEventListener(listener);
}

private class MyValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        setValue(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't listen to query " + query, databaseError.toException());
    }
}
```

}

As far as I know, I should get 'b1' when I print the log for batch id, when questid = 'q1', however I get 'batch' as the key.

```
2020-06-30 17:15:21.864 29487-29487/com.example.activedash D/sad: score calc quest id q1
2020-06-30 17:15:21.916 29487-29487/com.example.activedash D/sad: badge id badge
```

When I just put the key as child(key), instead of orderByChild() this works well but I need to get the key of badge through orderByChild()

```
 @NonNull
public LiveData<DataSnapshot> getBadgeSnapshotLiveData(String qid) {
    Query query = dbBadge.child("b1");
    return new FirebaseQueryLiveData(query);
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: okay, i added the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to take care of that list by looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. So if you indeed only expect one result, that be:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        setValue(snapshot);
    }
}
```